# Apache reverse proxy from root to context

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2

I am wondering if it is possible to configure Apache as a reverse proxy from `/path` to the root (`/`). I want to proxy `http://server1/path` to `http://server2:8080` but I am not having any luck. I am finding that the path on the proxy and the backend application path must match - either as `/path` or `/` - or I get 404s from the reverse proxy because it loses the path when the request returns. If it matters the backend application is running in tomcat.

To summarize: `Reverse proxy on http://server1/path -> Backend app on http://server2:8080/`

I have tried modrewrite to the best of my ability but not gotten it to work. Can I rewrite the path *after* being processed by the reverse proxy? Or is there a better way?

Comment: The best tip I can give you is to check the browsers console and map the reverseproxies according to that. This is a good example: https://serverfault.com/questions/799012/dynmap-throu-mod-proxy-on-a-external-webserver

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like that:

```
<Location "/path/">
    ProxyPass "http://server2:8080/"
</Location>
```

If so, what does not work?

Comment: I have tried it, and the target server (server2) is interpreting "path" as part of the request path

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ If you have a new question, post it as such. Make sure to provide details of your troubleshooting, because the excerpt above, and its behavior, is straight out of Apache documentation, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass