# Gitlab showing 404 while running behind nginx reverse proxy, all within a docker network

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, gitlab

As the title says, I'm trying to serve Gitlab through an nginx reverse proxy, with both programs being run in separate docker containers connected through a docker network. A picture as an example:

```
Linux Host
 ____________________________
|                            |
| Docker                     |
|  __________________________|
| |                          |
| | Docker network (test-net)|
| |  ________________________|
| | |                        |
| | | nginx        gitlab    | Only nginx has a port bound to the host (443).
| | | |   |        |   |     | TLS is terminated at nginx as well.
| | | |   |   -->  |   |     | in my test, I have nginx running as localhost.
| | | |___|        |___|     | To access gitlab, hit https://localhost/git/
| | |________________________|
| |__________________________|
|____________________________|
```

nginx runs with this docker command:

`docker run -dit --network=test-net --name=nginx -p 443:443 -v "$PWD/conf":/etc/nginx:ro nginx:alpine && docker logs -f nginx`

`nginx.conf`

```
<Removed unnecessary config from here, very basic setup>
http {
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        ssl_certificate localhost.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key localhost.key;
        ssl_protocols   TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        location /git/ {
            proxy_pass http://test/;
        }
    }
}
```

`gitlab.rb`

```
<only relevant parts added here>
external_url 'https://localhost'
nginx['listen_port'] = 80
nginx['listen_https'] = false
nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
 "Host" => "$http_host_with_default",
 "X-Real-IP" => "$remote_addr",
 "X-Forwarded-For" => "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for",
 "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "http",
 "Upgrade" => "$http_upgrade",
 "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on",
 "Connection" => "$connection_upgrade"
}
nginx['custom_error_pages'] = {
  '404' => {
    'title' => '404',
    'header' => 'You\'ve been hit by !! You\'ve been struck by ! A false URL.',
    'message' => 'Double check that URL! Is it correct?'
  }
}
```

`docker-compose.yml` for gitlab:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  gitlab:
    image: 'internal-docker-repo:1234/gitlab/gitlab-ce:11.8.3-ce.0'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'test'
    container_name: test
    volumes:
      - './config:/etc/gitlab:rw'
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
    external: true
    name: test-net
```

Internally (to docker networks) nginx is known as `nginx` and gitlab is known as `test`. I have confirmed I can ping each container from inside the other, using their container names.

As it is now, it *almost* works. When I go to `https://localhost/git/` on my linux host I get a 404 error page from gitlab, but no login screen.

[image: the 404 screen. Custom, so I know gitlab is running and picked up the configuration]

I'm obviously missing *something* but I'm not sure what it is. It's hard for me to tell if it's an NGinx configuration issue or a Gitlab configuration issue.

Log output when I hit `https://localhost/git/`

`nginx log output`:

```
172.19.0.1 - - [07/Jan/2020:21:28:35 +0000] "GET /git/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2289 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"
```

`gitlab log output`:

```
test      | ==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
test      | 172.19.0.3 - - [07/Jan/2020:21:28:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 2289 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"
test      | 
test      | ==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
test      | 2020-01-07_21:28:35.10649 test 127.0.0.1:0 - - [2020/01/07:21:28:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 3108 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" 0.001
test      |
```

Comment: I think it is somewhat related to this: https://serverfault.com/questions/799012/dynmap-through-mod-proxy-on-a-external-webserver
 - Try to inspect the page and check where the errors occur, and then remap it accordingly. Otherwhise, just use a subdomain for gitlab, you wont have that issue then.

Answer (score 1):

I think at least one of the problems (if not the most important) is the fact that gitlab expects https://localhost as the URL in your browser. Unfortunately, you're not giving it that, but https://localhost/git, although the request obviously reaches the backend (which is the gitlab container).

Changing the external url directive on the inner nginx to "https://localhost/git" might work as a quick fix. Obviously you need to reconfigure gitlab afterwards:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfig
```

If I were you, though, I would use a dedicated domain for gitlab (so a separate server block in nginx), as this would be cleaner to my mind.
Something to the effect of:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name gitlab.example.com;
        ssl_certificate localhost.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key localhost.key;
        ssl_protocols   TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://test/;
              }
        }
```

And then change the external_url, of course, to gitlab.example.com.

Since you're using the localhost anyway, I don't think it would be much bother if you added this new domain in /etc/hosts :
127.0.0.1 gitlab.example.com

Comment: The problem is that I'm actively trying to avoid using subdomains to proxy containers. While I've already confirmed I can proxy using subdomains, relative paths are easier to remember. For that reason I can't accept this answer, even though it is a way to go about proxying gitlab, and that anyone else who reads this should take using subdomains into account.

Only changing the `external_url` to have `/git` at the end didn't work. Looking at the logs it seems that the initial get request to the server 404's because nginx removes the `/git/` relative path when forwarding the request.

Answer (score 1):

## **Cause**

The reason you can't get connected is because of the `location` in Nginx mismatch the `external_url` URL defined in gitlab.rb.

In your Nginx configuration, you specify `location /git/`, while in the Gitlab configuration, you use `https://localhost`. This will cause the error: when a client requests to access `https://localhost/git` it will always tail the "git/" at the end of URI, however, your Gitlab is configured to access via `https://localhost`, so it will never be able to find the webpage!

## **Solution:**

As either change the `location /git/` to `location /` or change the `https://localhost` to `https://localhost/git`.

## **Example**

Here is my full configuration on my docker, you can take this as reference:

*Note: `172.16.0.10` is the IP of the Gitlab server, `gitlab.drive.nr` resolves the IP of the Nginx server

Nginx docker:

```
$ cat nginx-r.sh 
sudo docker run -itd --name=nginx-r \
    --network=testenv \
    --ip 172.16.0.3 \
    --dns 172.16.0.2 \
    -h rproxy.drive.nr \
    -p 80:80 -p 443:443 \
    -v nginx-config:/etc/nginx \
    -v nginx-certs:/etc/ssl/private \
    nginx:alpine
```

Gitlab docker:

```
$ cat gitlab.sh 
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname gitlab.drive.nr \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --network testenv \
  --ip 172.16.0.10 \
  --dns 172.16.0.2 \
  --volume gitlab-config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume gitlab-logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume gitlab-data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

Nginx configurations:

```
# cat conf.d/sites-enabled/gitlab.conf 
server {
  listen   80;
  location / {
    return 301 https://172.16.0.10;
    }
}

server {
  listen   443 ssl;
  server_name   gitlab.drive.nr;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/gitlab.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/gitlab.key;
  ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
  location /git {
    proxy_pass http://172.16.0.10;
  }
}
```

Gitlab configurations:

```
# cat gitlab-config/gitlab.rb |grep -v ^#
external_url 'http://gitlab.drive.nr/git'
```

## **Test Drive**

[image]

Log on Nginx:

```
172.16.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:23:35:26 +0000] "GET /git HTTP/1.1" 302 102 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"
172.16.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:23:35:26 +0000] "GET /git/users/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 302 150 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"
172.16.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:23:35:26 +0000] "GET /git/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=ayjmm32J3Ry_gDR8JbzU HTTP/1.1" 200 9502 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"
172.16.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:23:35:26 +0000] "GET /git/assets/application-aeddf31361633b3d1196c6483f25c484855e0f243e7f7e62686a4de9e10ec03b.css HTTP/1.1" 200 149097 "https://gitlab.drive.nr/git/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=ayjmm32J3Ry_gDR8JbzU" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"
172.16.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:23:35:26 +0000] "GET /git/assets/print-74c3df10dad473d66660c828e3aa54ca3bfeac6d8bb708643331403fe7211e60.css HTTP/1.1" 200 382 "https://gitlab.drive.nr/git/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=ayjmm32J3Ry_gDR8JbzU" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"
172.16.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:23:35:26 +0000] "GET /git/assets/webpack/runtime.ee78bc38.bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2134 "https://gitlab.drive.nr/git/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=ayjmm32J3Ry_gDR8JbzU" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"
172.16.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:23:35:26 +0000] "GET /git/assets/highlight/themes/white-3144068cf4f603d290f553b653926358ddcd02493b9728f62417682657fc58c0.css HTTP/1.1" 200 864 "https://gitlab.drive.nr/git/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=ayjmm32J3Ry_gDR8JbzU" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"
172.16.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:23:35:26 +0000] "GET /git/assets/webpack/main.b91d0a07.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 200 830262 "https://gitlab.drive.nr/git/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=ayjmm32J3Ry_gDR8JbzU" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"
172.16.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:23:35:26 +0000] "GET /git/assets/webpack/default.ca6f81b2.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 200 159 "https://gitlab.drive.nr/git/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=ayjmm32J3Ry_gDR8JbzU" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"
172.16.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:23:35:27 +0000] "GET /git/assets/icons-e91700f3f1ecff110fc2c35aa62aec8f2aad69d1bfb35844186a11175a79e25f.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 25983 "https://gitlab.drive.nr/git/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=ayjmm32J3Ry_gDR8JbzU" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"
172.16.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:23:35:27 +0000] "GET /git/assets/touch-icon-ipad-retina-8ebe416f5313483d9c1bc772b5bbe03ecad52a54eba443e5215a22caed2a16a2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5662 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"
172.16.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:23:35:27 +0000] "GET /git/assets/favicon-7901bd695fb93edb07975966062049829afb56cf11511236e61bcf425070e36e.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1611 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"
```

Comment: Thank you for going into such detail to answer the question I posed. I'll be awarding you the 100 bounty for the depth of answering, but it didn't fully fix my problem, so I wont be able to mark it as correct. I'll provide another comment later in the day describing what has happened, I'm late for a meeting now.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact problem described here.

The following settings made it work.

GitLab Docker:

```
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://<domain>/gitlab/'

[...]

    ports:
      - "8929:80"
```

NGINX:

```
   location /gitlab/ {

      #  ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
      #  ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
       proxy_read_timeout      300;
       proxy_connect_timeout   300;
       proxy_redirect          off;

       proxy_http_version 1.1;

       proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
       proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
       proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

       proxy_pass http://<domain>:8929/gitlab/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (both Gitlab and Nginx running as Docker containers).

The cause of my error was mistakenly using the `https` protocol when defining the `external_url` setting.

I.e. it should be:

```
external_url 'http://MY_DOMAIN'
```

rather than:

```
external_url 'https://MY_DOMAIN'
```

My Nginx config was handling the `http -> https` redirection for me.

I hope this helps people encountering the same problem.